# Pull request closed after changing base branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I followed instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) for changing the base branch of a pull request someone made on my repo. After changing the branch, though, the issue was closed and I don't think the merge was made. Any idea why or how I can still make the merge? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the link to your pull request?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dafriedman97/mlbook/pull/3), thanks!

Comment: The branch being merged is probably created from `master` which maybe ahead of `gh-pages`. See this - https://github.com/dafriedman97/mlbook/pull/3/commits/a8409b59acd5c6bdc5fc913b5295466b79698bf3